# Is there a way to use `@jit` annotation for a python function that accepts a fixed shape list argument?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, jit, numba

I am writing a python engine to play the `Gomoku` game.

I am representing a game position as a 2D list of integers, e.g:

```
position = [[0,0,0],[0,1,0],[-1,0,0]]
```

represents

[image]

`0` value indicates an empty cell, `1` indicates my stone, `-1` opponents stone. The actual list is of larger size: 19 x 19.

I have a python function:

```
def Evaluate(position):
    # some computation
    return score
```

that I want to optimize using `@jit` annotation. Unfortunately, an error is raised indicating that I can not use the list as a function argument:

```
Encountered 'reflected list' type that is scheduled for deprecation
```

Given that the dimension of my `position` variable will never change: the list will have a fixed shape `m x n` set at the beginning of the program, but the values inside the list CAN change (e.g. when I make a move I will make an assignment `position[0][0] = 1`), **is there a way to use `jit` annotations for such function**?

Comment: Why not simply using a numpy array? For lists it is described here https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/pysupported.html#list Numba make use of it's own list representation. But working with this lists outside of Numba could also be slower than with Python lists.

Comment: @max9111 `working with this list outside of Numba could also be slower than with Python lists` - that's exactly the reason why I'm not using numpy.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a numpy array? it will work way better in numba than any kind of list.

Comment: Numpy  array is much slower for the code that's not optimised